# How to use a group by but still access every number values cleverly

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I need to "group by" my data to distinguish between tests (each test has a specific id, name and temperature) and to calculate their count, standard deviation, etc. But I also need access every raw data value from each group, for further indexes calculations that I do in a python script.

I have found two solution to this problem, but both seems non-optimal/flawed:

1) Using **listagg** to store every raw value that were grouped into a single string row. It does the work but it is not optimized : I concatenate multiples float values into a giant string that I will immediately de-concatenate and convert back to float. That seem necessary and costly.

2) Removing the group by entirely and do the count and standard deviation though **partitioning**. But that seems even worse to me. I don't know if PLSQL/oracle optimizes this, it could be calculating the same count and standard deviation for every line (I don't know how to check this). The query result also becomes messy: since there is no 'group by' anymore, I have to do add multiple checks in my python file in order to differentiate every test data (specific id, name and temperature).

I think that my first solution can be improved but I don't know how. How can I use a group by but still access every number values **cleverly** ?

A function similar to list_agg but with a collection/array output type instead of a string output type could maybe do the trick (a sort of 'array_agg' compatible with oracle), but I don't know any.

EDIT:
The sample data is complex and probably restricted to the company viewing, but I can show you my simplified query for my 1) :

```
SELECT 
    rav.rav_testid as test_id, 
    tte.tte_testname as test_name,
    tsc.tsc_temperature as temperature,
    listagg(rav.rav_value, ' ')WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY rav.rav_value) as all_specific_test_values,
    COUNT(rav.rav_value) as n, 
    STDDEV(rav.rav_value) as sigma,

FROM
    ...
    (8 inner joins)


GROUP BY
    rav.rqv_testid, tte.tte_testname,tsc.tsc_temperature

ORDER BY
    rav.RAV_testid, tte.tte_testname, spd.SPD_SPLITNAMEINTERNAL,tsc.tsc_temperature
```

The result looks like :

```
test_id | test_name  | temperature | all_specific_test_values | n | sigma
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
6001    |VADC_A(...) | -40         | ,8094034194946289 ,8(...)| 58 | 0,54
6001    |VADC_A(...) |  25         | ,5054857852946545 ,6(...)| 56 | 0,24
6001    |VADC_A(...) |  150        | ,8625754277452524 ,4(...)| 56 | 0,26
6002    |VADC_B(...) | -40         | ,9874514651548454 ,5(...)| 57 | 0,44
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Sounds like maybe you don't want aggregate functions, but [analytic functions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm) instead. These won't collapse your rows like aggregate functions do.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want analytic functions:

```
select t.*,
       count(*) over (partition by test) as cnt,
       avg(value) over (partition by test) as avg_value,
       stddev(value) over (partition by test) as stddev_value
from t;
```

This adds additional columns on each row.

Comment: This is what I explored in my solution 2), my issue with this is that It make my query result messy (no more grouping corresponding to specifics tests) and may not be optimised : does server re-calculates the counts and redo its partition for every line though every line ?

Comment: @Pierre . . . Analytic functions are built-into Oracle and work has been done to optimize them.  They are usually the fastest method to accomplish the tasks that they do.

Comment: Indeed the 'Explain plan' tools showed that my worries where unfounded, there is only one 'window sort' needed' for the count and std_dev. Actually the total cost was even marginally reduced (33504 -> 33502). 

But strangely the execution time almost doubled (7s -> 12s)... It might because of transfer time ? Because now that every raw_value has it own line, more line need to be send than in solution 1)  (but with less data in each so that doesn't explain such a difference)

Comment: @Pierre . . . There is overhead to the DB returning more rows.  However, perhaps it is sufficient to have the values by groups and not by rows and you can use aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest going with @Gordon_Linoff's solution.  That is likely the most standard solution.

If you want to go with a less standard solution, you can have a `group by` that returns a collection as one of the columns.  Presumably, your script could iterate through that collection though it might take a bit of work in the script to do that.

```
create type num_tbl as table of number;
/

create table foo (
  grp integer,
  val number
);

insert into foo values( 1, 1.1 );
insert into foo values( 2, 1.2 );
insert into foo values( 1, 1.3 );
insert into foo values( 2, 1.4 );

select grp, avg(val), cast( collect( val ) as num_tbl )
  from foo
 group by grp
```

Comment: _"A function similar to list_agg but with a collection/array output type instead of a string output type"_.  This sounds like just what the doctor ordered.  Why do you view this as "less standard"?

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak - It's a lot less common to return a collection in a result set.  That means it's a lot less likely that whatever ORM/ API you're using to access the database is going to have a robust, well-documented way of handling a collection in the result.  It may mean that you get less optimal performance at the network level-- I haven't tested this but I know that, say, when I had a result set where one of the columns was a cursor, you ended up doing an extra network round-trip on every row to actually fetch the data from that cursor.

Comment: Basically, my bias is that if I can do something following a well-trod path, I'd rather do that than do something that relatively few people are doing.

Comment: I have actually used this approach specifically to avoid the network round-trip problems of using `CURSOR` columns.  The collection column does not seem to suffer the same problem.  Good point about the ORM tools -- I generally don't use those so I wouldn't have considered that.

Comment: I still prefer your answer.  I'll keep my upvote if you don't mind ;)